# Best way for AWS Lambda to communicate simple information/states

Tags: aws-lambda

I have an application where an initial lambda will spawn several asynchronous lambdas, and some of those lambdas may spawn their own asynchronous lambdas, and so on (although with a generation-counter to prevent runaways). The lambdas all currently write to a DynamoDB table. I'd like to know when the last one finishes, so as to kick off some different processes.

I can think of several ways generally:

- writing specific fields to the DB, and each lambda checks if it's the last one running
- SQS
- SWF (Step Functions/state machines)

I'd like to know the simplest way to do this, and/or the "best" or canonical way, if there is one. Would also like to avoid SQS (although I'm going to experiment with SWF anyway, just because it sounds cool).

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for AWS Step Functions.

The [Parallel](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html) state is exactly what you need.

> The Parallel state ("Type": "Parallel") can be used to create parallel branches of execution in your state machine.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to say if it would work, but will note that not all of the lambdas are starting at the exact same time from the same process. I updated the question, to indicate more clearly that there are multiple generations of lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario best fits with [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) where you can define the [Parallel state](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html) for Lambda steps and at the last execution to trigger the final step, which will kick of the different process. However this will simplify the state machine but will incur additional cost for individual states.

Another approach is to use DynamoDB [Atomic Counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) to keep track of each execution so that after the last execution, the Lambda function attached to the Stream, can identify and kick of the different process.

Answer (score 0):

You can also launch the lambda functions synchronously in parallel from your main lambda function. For example, in python it can be done using `Pipe` and `Process` from the `multiprocessing` library. You can then receive the responses from your parallel lambdas (max 6MB) as you would normally when using the `Pipe` module.